# how to add string in iphone differentiate with separator " ,"?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I think it's silly question but i dont know what to do with this.There are lots of order generated each order price string come in this format  "123,145,234,33,8," this is for one order only can you please tell me how can i add all this value and get the sum of all like "123+145+234+33+8" =  543 .the sum i have to show into tableview for each order.
i stuck on these please i develop this stuff for iphone please give me information with code.

Thank You.
If the information is not complete let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Split the string by `,`, convert to numbers and sum them up:

```
NSArray *parts = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
for (NSString *s in parts) {
    sum += [s integerValue];
}
```

If your string always has an additional trailing `,`, you could e.g. trim it by using:

```
NSRange trimRange = NSMakeRange(0, [myString length]-1);
NSString *trimmed = [myString substringWithRange:trimRange];
```

... or by using [`-stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-CJBJFBGC) if your needs are more complex.

Comment: I appreciate your answer is really solve my problem but when i try with this i got unexpected no. the problem because at the end of my whole string i got "," you can see i above describe like "123,145,234,33,8," also values come like "123.0,145.3,234.66,33.9,8.8," can you please help more about it.-@Georg Fritzsche

Comment: @prath: If you have fractional prices you might want to go with [`NSDecimalNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000179-decimalNumberWithString_) here.

Answer (score 0):

A little modification to Georg Fritzsche's answer

```
NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];

//// Remove last object. You might want to make sure it's always the case. ////
[array removeLastObject];

//// Here's a cool trick using Collection Operators. ////
NSNumber* sum = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.intValue"];

NSInteger k = [sum intValue];
```